# Wrapper for code block

Tags: c#, word-wrap, action

For example i have a datagrid and want to do something with it before databinding and after databinding, like so:

```
dgvTasksDocList.SaveLayoutToFile();
sTATUSCHANGESEXTENDEDBindingSource.DataSource = dt;
dgvTasksDocList.RestoreLayoutFromFile();
```

And i want to add such code with all that cases when binding some sources. Is there an easy way to write such code before/after some action(Sure i can add this 2 lines, but may be there is some known way of doing such things)?

Comment: Why exactly do you think those 3 lines wouldn't work in all cases.  If you want to do something before and after you bind your data then you have to do it.  There is no other way around that fact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be a case for AOP - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming.

For example with PostSharp you will be able to create an attribute `PersistLayout` and apply it like this:

```
[PersistLayout]
public void BindDataSource(object dt)
{
    sTATUSCHANGESEXTENDEDBindingSource.DataSource = dt;
}
```

Then Postsharp will extent source-code at compile-time to invoke your additional two-lines.

Other idea might be to invoke these two methods in `sTATUSCHANGESEXTENDEDBindingSource.DataSource` property setter but this decision needs a lot more context to know.

Comment: Except it still is doing the what he could simply write himself by making the method save and load the layout.  I don't see any benefit of using PostSharp for such a simple task.

Comment: @Ramhound - totally agreed.  I love AOP / PostSharp, but this is like using a nuclear device to open a door.

Comment: So you all think that the best way is just to write pre/post strings to accomplish my task? Ok, then i'll write extension method for BindingSource to save grid's layouts and provide some datasource to it. Thank you all for answers. Will mark this answer as ANSWER, because actually Snowbear is right :), we sure can achieve that with postsharp.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MyDGV : DataGridView
{
    public MyDGV()
    {
        DataSourceChanged += (s, e) => SaveLayoutToFile();
        DataBindingComplete += (s, e) => RestoreLayoutFromFile();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you :) another solution.. Ive made it so: dgvTasksDocList.BindSourceAndSaveLayouts(sTATUSCHANGESEXTENDEDBindingSource, dt);

Answer (score 0):

Made it just with extension method, so now it looks like:

```
dgvTasksDocList.BindSourceAndSaveLayouts(sTATUSCHANGESEXTENDEDBindingSource, dt);
```

Or even:

```
dgvTasksDocList.BindSourceAndSaveLayouts(dt);
```

Because `dgvTasksDocList.DataSource` can be casted to `BindingSource`(sure i MUST provide that `BindingSource`)